# Defining different validations based on the action method which is called in a Struts2 action

Tags: java, forms, validation, struts2, annotations

I'm creating a web application with Struts 2. In a JSP file, I created a form like this :

```
<s:form action="actionclassname!%{methodToCall}" method="post">
...
</s:form>
```

In the action class, I created two methods which will be called depending on the value of the variable `methodToCall`. That works well.
My problem is that the two methods of the action class need some validations. So I used annotations to validate the form if the first method is called :

```
@Validations(....) 
public String actionMethod1(){
    ...
}

@Validations(...) 
public String actionMehod2(){
    ...
}
```

The first method works well with validations. My problem is on the second method. It seems like when I define validations (also using annotations) for this second method, the validations I defined on first method are executed again before those I defined for the second method.

How to make validations on the second method to run when it's this method which is called by the JSP?

Comment: Are you determined to use annotations? I'm not sure this is really supported, but I also tend to not use annotations for stuff like this to keep my classes as neutral as possible.

Comment: Yes, I would like to keep using annotations.

Answer (score 0):

In the action configuration via annotation you should use a parameter `validateAnnotatedMethodOnly` for validation interceptor, like in this example

```
@Action(value="actionclassname", results = {
  @Result(name="input", location = "/actionclassname.jsp")
},interceptorRefs = @InterceptorRef(value="defaultStack", params = {"validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true"}))
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but it didn't work. I didn't use the defaultStack. Instead, i used the one I created. Does that matter in the result? Even with the defaultStack it doesn't work. Validations are always stacked up. Any oher suggestion?

Comment: @PatrickB. How could I know which stack are you using if you didn't post the code? And put annotation on method, used to map your action.

Comment: I wasn't blaming you on which stack I had to use. I put my annotations on methods used to map my action. It didn't work.

Comment: He also said it doesn't work with the default stack. Omitting a detail doesn't make it off-topic, and you know it doesn't.